# Filtering Table with CheckBox

Tags: javascript, filter, bootstrap-4

I would like to use checkbox as a filter and if user select checkbox, table only shows rows with checkbox are selected.

With Bootstrap

I tired Bootstap with text and it is working. But i couldn't figure out how to do it with check box.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function ()
    {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#activityTable tr").filter(function ()
        {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

Above code only works with text information.
Does anyone knows how to update this code for checkbox please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give an id to the checkbox and then get it's state. Let's say it's id is `chkBox` then you will have to write like:

```
var isChecked = $("#chkBox").is(':checked');
```

and then use it in your filter function:

```
$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
         && (isChecked && $(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')));
```

and if you meant was to show only rows where checkbox state is checked when user types in fitler box then:

```
$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
           &&  $(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')
              );
```

Now this will look in the `tr` for checkbox and if it is checked that row will be toggled.